# Все значения столбца поместить в Arraylist

Tags: java, mysql

Имеется столбец в базе `userID`, нужно все значения это столбца заполнить в `Arraylist`. Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью классов:

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "admin");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet srs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM userID");
        while (srs.next()) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(srs.getString("Name"));
            person.setJobtitle(srs.getString("Job"));
            personlist.add(person);
        }
```

Класс Person:

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private String jobtitle;

public String getJobtitle() {
    return jobtitle;
}

public void setJobtitle(String jobtitle) {
    this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: мне нужно взять все значения из столбцы и занести их в arraylist

Comment: Например так:

            string temp = "";
            while(srs.next())
            {
            ArrayList.add(srs.getString());
            }